# Populate dropdown data from json result

Tags: ajax, json, drop-down-menu

I tried searching and trying different things but unfortunately I can't find an answer that fits my situation.

I have this json format as a result of my (ajax)query

```
[{"id":1,"region":"Region I","state_id":1},{"id":2,"region":"Region II","state_id":1},{"id":3,"region":"Region III","state_id":1},{"id":4,"region":"Region IV-A","state_id":1},{"id":5,"region":"Region IV-B","state_id":1},{"id":6,"region":"Region V","state_id":1},{"id":16,"region":"CAR","state_id":1},{"id":17,"region":"NCR","state_id":1}]
```

How can I populate this data on my region dropdown list? I've tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#state").on('change', function () {
var state = $('#state').val();
    $.ajax({
        type    :"GET",
        url     :"http://localhost/laravel/public/getregions",
        dataType:"html",
        data    :{ stateid:state },

        success :function(response){
            alert(response);
            $($.parseJSON(response)).map(function () {
                return $('<option>').val(this.id).text(this.region);
            }).appendTo('#region');
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

but I get a TypeError: a is undefined error. I don't know if there's something wrong in my format or how I parse the json.

Answer (score 0):

The [map](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function expects an array as first argument and a function as second argument.

You do get an array of objects as an answer, so give it to the map function as first the argument. Then in the callback you can get each objects :

```
$.map(response,function(element,index){ ... });
```

Check the jsfiddle to see if that works for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/xo8dq98t/1/

Answer (score 0):

To populate your region dropdown from ajax call, I would try this approach:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    var regions = [];
    $.each(response, function(i, region) {
        regions.push('<option value="' + region.id + '">' + region.region + '</option>');
        $("#region").html(regions.join(''));
    });
});
```

Not fully tested though, but something similar should work. Good luck :)